# How to generate UML documentation from running application

Tags: documentation, uml, reverse-engineering, use-case

I have software that is implemented and in use by the end-user. I want to document it, in UML and use-cases, by reverse-engineering. By doing this, I expect that the documentation will be correct.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

**Simply NO**

There is no UML tool which can generate automatically use case diagram from source code-exe- application form.

**What you can do? [ Software Archaeology ]**

**First Find Who Use The System?**

Find the actual users [ the guys that use that software in daily work ].
Ask them : "What you do with the system"?

**Become an end-user**

Spend time with actual users, learn how system is used  like an end user.

**Check If there is a end user Manuel**

If there is one, then that will help you to understand system. But be careful it may be outdated. Check it with actual users and by yourself by using system.

**Vision ?**

No need  fancy visions after project finished. Just simple elevator statement.
Ask the question to do guys who wanted to build system : Product Owner.

[image]

[image]

**How About Software Documentation**

Be creative and open minded. Documentation should not have to be on "paper".
Find a video cam and  a white board. Take the guys who program the system.
Ask them to explain their system by talking and drawing diagrams.And record it.

That is also a documentation.

Comment: Is there any way to find “include ” or “extend” relationship ?for example if the code is used “if-else”, relationship is “extend”.

Comment: No. Use Cases are Requirements which are written in a story-text format. They are high level. They have no one-to-one mapping with code. Include or extends relationships have nothing with source code "else-if" structure.

Comment: I have one question again,if I want to writting system features in Vision Document,is there any way to find it, from application forms?

Comment: in overal view I am so confusing for documentation software,is there any way for this work?

Comment: Well, the system is finished. Why create "vision" document at this stage?

Comment: because the system has been transferred to programmer ,and new programmer not familiar to this sytem at all.

Comment: thanx for spend your time and answer my Question.